# Edit Text first character as $

Tags: android, android-edittext, currency

I am working on one of my android project.
what I want is to keep first character as $ in my Edit text and user should not remove this first character by pressing back button of soft keyboard.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use Keypress event.

Comment: Merge textview with edittext.

Comment: That's not the right way to think about it. What you really should be doing is putting a TextView next to the EditText for the currency symbol.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind reply. but I am curios for some coding which solves this problem of mine.

Comment: If so, try something, show us code, and mention where you get stuck. No one will code for you! **Hint: TextWatcher**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this you have to use a layout like below.Here the dollar symbol is set in a text view and an `EditText` is place near to it. As the comments in your question said this is one of the best way to achieve this. if you want the text from `Edittext` including the $ symbol append it with the Text in `EdtText`.

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="price"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**For get the text including $ symbol do this:**

```
String text = et_text.getText().toString();
String text_withsymbol = "$" + et_text.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:**

I just put **"$"** symbol before edittext.i not **copy @Remees M Syde code.**

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relFirst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etCostof"
                    style="@style/IncomeText"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:inputType="number" >
                </EditText>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etCostof"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

No conses in editext.